# LINQ Expression starting with From and Aggregate is confusing

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following sample code:

```
Class Parent
   Public Property Id As Integer
   Public Property Name As String
End Class
Class Child
   Public Property Id As Integer
   Public Property ParentId As Integer
   Public Property Name As String
End Class
Module Module1

   Sub Main()
      Dim parent1 As New Parent With {.Id = 1, .Name = "Alvin"}
      Dim parent2 As New Parent With {.Id = 2, .Name = "Ben"}
      Dim child1 As New Child With {.Id = 100, .ParentId = 1, .Name = "Chester"}
      Dim child2 As New Child With {.Id = 101, .ParentId = 1, .Name = "David"}
      Dim ParentList As New List(Of Parent)({parent1, parent2})
      Dim ChildList As New List(Of Child)({child1, child2})

      Dim result = _
         From p In ParentList _
         Aggregate c In ChildList Where c.ParentId = p.Id _
         Into FirstOrDefault() _
         Where FirstOrDefault Is Nothing OrElse FirstOrDefault
   End Sub

End Module
```

The LINQ query going into "result" is incomplete because I'm stumped at what is happening there. I expect FirstOrDefault to refer to refer to a single Child object at that point in the expression, but it refers to a collection of child objects. Why? What is the best way to get a list of parents that have no associated child or have a child fitting a particular condition? (My actual code will have one child max, so this sample code is not representative.)

I just don't understand what the collection of FirstOrDefault could be referring to. It should really be just 1 value or nothing at all times.

Comment: You're possibly looking for [`Enumerable.SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter SingleOrDefault has the same problem. Both of these functions are supposed to return 0 or 1 record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer to the piece about how to do it properly, but I'm still hard pressed to understand what FirstOrDefault is referring to when I *don't* do it this way:

```
  Dim result = _
     (From p In ParentList _
     Aggregate c In ChildList Where c.ParentId = p.Id _
     Into FirstOrDefault() _
     Select p, FirstOrDefault).Where( _
     Function(r) r.FirstOrDefault Is Nothing OrElse r.FirstOrDefault.Name < r.p.Name)
```

**Edit:** It looks like there's a bug in the Intellisense that suggests that FirstOrDefault is a collection of Child objects when in fact it *is* just a single Child, and you *can* use it as such. I am able to use the same expression in the original query and everything works fine. Intellisense just led me astray.